# How to set the value of a Progression bar from a different activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I have a int value in `MainActivity` and I want to move it in the second activity and there set it as a value for a Progression bar. I tried the following situation but it doesn’t seem to work. Any tips will be appreciated.

`MainActivity`:

```
public void subQ8Clicked(View v) {
calculateScore();

Q7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Intent ResultActivity = new Intent(MathActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
ResultActivity.putExtra("Score",score);
startActivity(ResultActivity);}
```

`ResultActivity`:

```
Intent ResultActivity=getIntent();
int valScor=ResultActivity.getIntExtra("Score",0);
ProgressBar CurrentProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progressbar);
CurrentProgress.setMax(100);
CurrentProgress.setMin(0);
CurrentProgress.setProgress(valScor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ResultActivity.getExtras().getInt("Score")`, instead of `ResultActivity.getIntExtra("Score",0)`

Comment: tried it, doesn't seem to affect the behavior of the progression bar.

Comment: Please, try to call  `CurrentProgress.setProgress(60)`,  then say me what happened

Comment: So,probably the problem is with progress bar

Comment: Is it visible in screen , when  you are running your app ?

Comment: Yes, it is visible.